# How to change format of date and time format in excelwhich is combined

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a date formate like 12-feb-17  07.54.34.340000000 AM to format 2/2/17 07:54 AM
How to convert to this using Excel?

Answer (score 2):

the first 2 `.` need to be `:`.  Use this formula and then format the result as desired:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":"),":",".",3)
```

[image]

Comment: Format cell is not converting it to desired format :(

Comment: did you put the formula exactly like I did with the `--` in front?